# One way hash of data records (PBKDF2?)

Tags: pbkdf-2

I'm looking for a way of one way hash data for multiple records. We have a privacy requirement to anonymise information "after it's used for its intended purpose" which is a little wooly at best.

I'd therefore like to delete everything once a project is finished, but this has been met with pushback internally "in case clients as follow up questions", so I figure the next best way is to hash the data with a one way system, so, it's effectively anonymized, not even we'd know what it was, but, if supplied with an email address (for instance) to lookup, we could hash it and search for a match in our database.

I'd need something that non-technical users could use and wouldn't be overly onerous in time, as it's an uphill battle to get people compliant already.

Hoping for an excel solution, or something that could load an excel/csv in and spit out the hashed version, however everything I look at for PBKDF2 is for implementing in websites or similar, singular password use.

I managed to get SHA256 working in excel, but as there's no salt they can be reversed with some work, meaning our effort to make the data anonymised is disingenuous, which is where i came across PBKDF2.

As you can tell be reading this far, I'm a bit out of my depth and would like to appeal to those who know more than I for any help!

Comment: _"I managed to get SHA256 working in excel, but as there's no salt they can be reversed with some work"_ ? Isn't that quite tricky? How long is each record?

Comment: We'll be hashing personal data, so names, email addresses etc.. so fields could be four to over forty characters. It's less of a practical thing though and more of the theoretical, so we can check a box to say we've done this to the best possible way, if you get me?

Comment: I do and don't  :-( but happy to help :-)  PBKDF2 is used for reversible encryption, but that's neither here nor there.  My problem is your 1st & 2nd paragraph.  You seem to require quasi anonymous data which seems less than anonymous.  But anonymity is a binary condition.  And reversing SHA256(favourite colour|name|email) is currently impossible. I think that you need to flesh out paras.1 & 2 as cryptography is not anonymity.   Asking the right question is 50% of the answer...

Comment: Sorry Paul. So I want anonymity in the regards that if you don't know the answer you can work it out (so, say rainbow tables could give you the result of a basic md5 hash pretty easily).
But, if we have an email, say example@the.net and a salt of example@the.net (unique salt) for 1k iterations & key length 32 you will get the hash:
E4AE2A011E2B6454B384B33EB55E8BFAAE057D7C60C872C5F2F2E25BCC90C76A
Now, it'd be pretty difficult to reverse that, but, in the future if someone goes, "did you contact example@the.net" I can re-apply the above process & get the same hash to search for in my records.

Comment: If someone stole my dataset, it'd be meaningless to them, as it's all hash, but, it's still functional to us if we get queries after our anonymisation process as we can lookup email addresses and check the none personal data fields that weren't hashed, like contact dates, number of attempts and outcomes etc..

Comment: Ahhh!   So database recordID = HASH(email address)?   It's not anonymous if you can remember the email address(es) though.  Anonymisation is an irreversible  one way process to my mind. But does it all come down to _"If someone stole my dataset dot dot dot?"_  I think that you might actually be looking for _privacy_ rather than _anonymity_.

Comment: Database encryption seems a better fit, with a key known only to the company.  If someone stole your dataset, it'd be meaningless to them, as it's all random looking, but, it's still functional to you.

Comment: Thanks Paul, sadly the database is provided by a third party (part of their survey platform) so this is not an option for us, and apologies for the incorrect terminology, I'm just trying to find the best compromise for what's right, however, I found out today this is all moot as a new Australian law means we have to be able to de-crypt everything if the police ask anyway because terrorism, which seems like a whole bigger issue for companies larger than us.

Answer (score 1):

Even with PBKDF2, You wouldn't be able to use salt anyways, because salting relies on a one-to-one mapping between the salt and a user identifier (email). You cannot keep the email, so you wouldn't know which salt to use when a user comes back with his email.

Simply iterating SHA 256 for a large number of times is a way to discourage preimage searching. Other (more solid) cost-incurring algorithms include scrypt. Although time-space balance attacks still work if you don't have salt to work with. (Using SHA, possibly inserting large constant data after input string to further slow it down).

Comment: Note that iterating SHA-256 can slightly reduce security since it risks hitting a short cycle. This isn't a realistic concern for a good 256-bit hash function, but it'd be dangerous to conclude that _any_ hash can be made slower more securely just by iterating it.

Comment: @forest, Hi, I'm confused to what you are saying. I'm thinking that if you have some input, and then you do SHA(x) = y, and then SHA(y) = z and so on, then you are in a SHA cycle. But however many iterations of SHA you do, you are still in this same cycle, is that right?

Comment: There are a large number of cycles, some large, some small. For a hash with a large output space, most are going to be very large, but there's always a chance that you can hit a small one.

Comment: Yes. But is it possible to enter a small cycle after reaching a large cycle first?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. You're only going to hit one cycle and cycles are, by definition, cyclic, so once in one, you're stuck. It's better to be stuck in one so huge that there are no security issues than one which is small enough that the space may be enumerable.

Comment: I got it, iterating sha does not make you enter into another cycle, but it exposes the fact you are in a short cycle if you are indeed in one. Thanks for clarifying.